# #->ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

Tags: python, mysql, weak-references

This is the code produce error:

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

class Command:
    def __init__(self):
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', passwd='1234', user='root', database='customers')

        self.mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    def execute(self, contest_id, url, Questions):
        date = datetime.date.today()
        Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M")

        self.mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO contest(contest_name, url_tag, Questions, At_date, At_time) VALUES('{contest_id}', '{url}', {Questions}, '{date}', '{Time}')")
```

I am running a Python code and I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
   File "C:\python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 518, in execute
    if not self._connection:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your connection got lost, since it's not attribute to your class. Can you try it this way?

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

class Command:
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', passwd='1234', user='root', database='customers')

        self.mycursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def execute(self, contest_id, url, Questions):
        date = datetime.date.today()
        Time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M")

        self.mycursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO contest(contest_name, url_tag, Questions, At_date, At_time) VALUES('{contest_id}', '{url}', {Questions}, '{date}', '{Time}')")
```

Comment: Yeah, This code is working partially but when i am updating my database then these column in not visible and when i insert a line from mysql workbench and after refresh mysql window I see, id column executed that time but those lines are not visible.